# Error only callback in async npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am using this [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module for asynchronously requesting
  web content with the help of another module [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), as this is an asynchronous call.
  Using [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) method, for requesting data from each link,
  the result is also successfully returned by the `scrap()` function (which I have wrote to scrap returned html data
  and return it as array of fuel prices by state).

Now, the problem is that when I try to return prices back to `async.each()` using `cb(null, prices)`, it shows `console.log(prices)` as `undefined`
  but logging inside the `_check_fuel_prices()`, works fine. It seems the callback works with only one argument
  (or error only callback, as show as an example in the `async.each` link above). What if I want to it return prices (I can change it with error  like `cb(prices)`, but I also want to log error).

```
router.get('/someRoute', (req, res, next) => {
    const fuels = ['diesel', 'petrol'];
    async.each(fuels, _check_fuel_prices, (err, prices) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            console.log(prices);
            return res.json(prices);
        }
        res.statusCode = 400;
        return res.json(err);
    });

    function _check_fuel_prices(fuel, cb) {
        let prices = '';
        const url_string = 'http://some.url/';
        request(`${url_string}-${fuel}-price/`, (error, response, html) => {
            if (error) {
                cb(error, null);
                return;
            }
            if (response.statusCode === 404) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                cb('UNABLE TO FIND PAGE', null);
                return;
            }
            prices = scrap(html, fuel);
            console.log(prices);
            cb(null, prices);
            return;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't just `return` results in an async callback and expect it to do something - it has to be processed externally somehow (using `Promise.all()` instead of `async.each` for example).  The rest of the code has long been executed by the time this runs so nothing sees that `return` value

Comment: It's because async.each just runs the functions and calls back with the error.  You want async.map which will callback an array as you're expecting.  http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@generalhenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491845/generalhenry) points out, I was able to get the `prices` by using `async.map` which returns error first callback instead of error only apart from that `async.series` can be used here by slightly changing the code.